# how can I use NSISO8601DateFormatOptions with PyObjC

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, pyobjc

In calling NSISO8601DateFormatter to format a timestamp from NSDate, I'd like to set options for the formatting.
Like NSISO8601DateFormatWithSpaceBetweenDateAndTime as described in [the documentation for NSISO8601DateFormatOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsiso8601dateformatter/1643324-formatoptions?language=objc)

I can't seem to how to specify the necessary import in Python, and how to apply the options. I can't find the NSISO8601DateFormatter in [the library repo](https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc) like with e.g. NSTimeZone but yet the NSISO8601DateFormatter import works.

I've tried the import with the commented lines, but that gives `ImportError: cannot import name`...

I'm testing on a Mac running macOS 11.2.3 and default python 2.7.16

Example output:

`2021-04-01T12:55:41+02:00 [py_objc_timestamp] timestamp from PyObjC`

Example of desired output:

`2021-04-01 12:55:41+02:00 [py_objc_timestamp] timestamp from PyObjC`

This is my testing code, it's working aside from the lines commented out.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# coding=utf-8

import CoreFoundation
from Foundation import (NSDate,
    NSISO8601DateFormatter,
    NSTimeZone)
#from Foundation import kCFISO8601DateFormatWithSpaceBetweenDateAndTime
#from Foundation import NSISO8601DateFormatOptions


def timestamp(dt=None):
    if not dt:
        dt = NSDate.date() # use now
    the_format = NSISO8601DateFormatter.alloc().init()
    the_format.setTimeZone_(NSTimeZone.localTimeZone())
    #the_format.formatOptions = { kCFISO8601DateFormatWithSpaceBetweenDateAndTime }
    timestamp = the_format.stringFromDate_(dt)
    return timestamp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (timestamp() + " [py_objc_timestamp] timestamp from PyObjC")
```

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: don't have my mac on hand and can't test any of this

this, however, is the header you're looking for:
https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/CoreFoundation/Locale.subproj/CFDateFormatter.h#L53

these are constants.

Here's how we load these:

```
from Foundation import NSBundle

# Load the framework bundle by its identifier
Foundation_bundle = NSBundle.bundleWithIdentifier_("com.apple.Foundation")
objc.loadBundleVariables(Foundation_bundle, globals(), [('kCFISO8601DateFormatWithSpaceBetweenDateAndTime', '@')])
```

this will load the constant in as a python variable you can now use.

More info here (ctrl + f loadBundleVariables):
https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metadata/manual.html

Comment: The manual load failed. When I attempt to use the constant to initialize formatOptions, it thows `'kCFISO8601DateFormatWithSpaceBetweenDateAndTime' is not defined`. Also when I add False for skip_undefined as last parameter for `objc.loadBundleVariables` it throws an error in a Try block.

Comment: not horribly familiar with pyobjc; you could try just manually entering the value from the headers (1UL << 2 would be 1 << 2 in python) and see if that gets you anywhere

Comment: looks like that's what red_menace's answer suggests.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks for the clue with the manual loading. It appears the manual loading does not support loading enumerator constants.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t look like those enumerator constants are defined in PyObjC’s `bridgesupport` file, but their values can still be used by looking them up in the Foundation documentation.  Note that *all* the individual pieces need to be included when creating the formatting mask:

```
kCFISO8601DateFormatWithFullDate = 275
kCFISO8601DateFormatWithFullTime = 1632
kCFISO8601DateFormatWithSpaceBetweenDateAndTime = 128
```

A bitwise operation is typically used to get the mask, but adding those gives a value of 2035.

Another issue is setting the format options.  Currently that is a property, but in this case a setter method needs to be used instead (it can vary depending on the particular framework).

Putting all that together, the commented import statements are not needed, and the formatting statement (tested in Catalina and Big Sur) becomes:

```
the_format.setFormatOptions_(2035)
```

Comment: Yes, that tests OK for me too. I had actually tried the same last night after some guesswork before I saw your answer this morning. Seems like an ugly hack though. Wonder where I could check if such constants or other elements are missing from the PyObjc bridgesupport  file - which file is it actually?

Comment: I didn’t find anything in the framework itself, and don’t know how/if PyObjC uses the Foundation/Core Foundation ones (which do have the enums), so it may just be an older version since Apple doesn’t use the latest.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I did some more research to learn about the NSISO8601DateFormatOptions constants not being supported by PyObjC, so posting my own answer with updated test code for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after getting help from [krit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13062807/krit) and [red_menace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10853463/red-menace) in the other two answers and doing some more research of my own.

The best clue I could find about not being able to import the NSISO8601DateFormatOptions constants from Foundation is that the constant I was looking for `kCFISO8601DateFormatWithFractionalSeconds` only appears in `aliases` in [a PyObjC Foundation metadata file](https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/blob/238b8fce06ef36fab4e0e0ef8d10aa12a64a0af8/pyobjc-framework-Cocoa/Lib/Foundation/_metadata.py). In comparison, `kCFPreferencesCurrentHost` which CAN be imported from CoreFoundation appears in  `constants` in a similar metadata file in that repo.

Maybe a future version of PyObjC will support importing these constants.

Here's my updated test code that demonstrates how we can define the different constants manually, I added all of them in case someone with similar needs comes looking here.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8

# File: py_objc_timestamp.py
# Demonstrates how to get ISO8601 / RFC3339 Internet timestamps
# using PyObjC bridge and Foundation framework

import CoreFoundation
from Foundation import (NSDate,
    NSISO8601DateFormatter,
    NSTimeZone)

'''
It doesn’t look like NSISO8601DateFormatOptions constants are covered by PyObjC’s
    bridgesupport file - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66933245/4326287
They're listed not as constants or enums but as aliases in
    https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/blob/master/pyobjc-framework-Cocoa/Lib/CoreFoundation/_metadata.py
'''
try:
    from Foundation import (kCFISO8601DateFormatWithInternetDateTime, \
        kCFISO8601DateFormatWithFullTime)
except:
    '''
    manually defining constants for option flag bits, gleaning constants and values from
    https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/CoreFoundation/Locale.subproj/CFDateFormatter.h#L53
    '''
    print("[py_objc_timestamp] import of NSISO8601DateFormatOptions constants from Foundation failed, defining manually")
    kCFISO8601DateFormatWithYear = 1 << 0
    kCFISO8601DateFormatWithMonth = 1 << 1
    kCFISO8601DateFormatWithWeekOfYear = 1 << 2
    kCFISO8601DateFormatWithDay = 1 << 4
    kCFISO8601DateFormatWithTime = 1 << 5
    kCFISO8601DateFormatWithTimeZone = 1 << 6
    kCFISO8601DateFormatWithSpaceBetweenDateAndTime = 1 << 7
    kCFISO8601DateFormatWithDashSeparatorInDate = 1 << 8
    kCFISO8601DateFormatWithColonSeparatorInTime = 1 << 9
    kCFISO8601DateFormatWithColonSeparatorInTimeZone = 1 << 10
    kCFISO8601DateFormatWithFractionalSeconds = 1 << 11
    #kCFISO8601DateFormatWithFullDate = 275
    kCFISO8601DateFormatWithFullDate = kCFISO8601DateFormatWithYear | \
        kCFISO8601DateFormatWithMonth | kCFISO8601DateFormatWithDay | \
        kCFISO8601DateFormatWithDashSeparatorInDate
    #kCFISO8601DateFormatWithFullTime = 1632
    kCFISO8601DateFormatWithFullTime = kCFISO8601DateFormatWithTime | \
        kCFISO8601DateFormatWithColonSeparatorInTime | \
        kCFISO8601DateFormatWithTimeZone | \
        kCFISO8601DateFormatWithColonSeparatorInTimeZone
    # Default - int(1907)
    kCFISO8601DateFormatWithInternetDateTime = kCFISO8601DateFormatWithFullDate | \
        kCFISO8601DateFormatWithFullTime

# define as global, need to setup only once
timestamp_format = NSISO8601DateFormatter.alloc().init()

# I'm a fan of local timezone timestamps rather than UTC, easier in testing software
timestamp_format.setTimeZone_(NSTimeZone.localTimeZone())

# Give us a Internet style, timezone-aware format, space instead of T for readability
timestamp_format_format_options = kCFISO8601DateFormatWithInternetDateTime | \
    kCFISO8601DateFormatWithSpaceBetweenDateAndTime
print("[py_objc_timestamp] NSISO8601DateFormatOptions add up to: %i" % timestamp_format_format_options)
timestamp_format.setFormatOptions_(timestamp_format_format_options)
# If you absolutely must have speed rather than readability, you can strip the
# formatting constants and hardcode the combined value instead
# timestamp_format.setFormatOptions_(2035)

def timestamp(dt=None):
    if not dt:
        dt = NSDate.date() # use now
    timestamp = timestamp_format.stringFromDate_(dt)
    return timestamp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (timestamp() + " [py_objc_timestamp] timestamp from PyObjC")
```

Example of output:

```
[py_objc_timestamp] import of NSISO8601DateFormatOptions constants from Foundation failed, defining manually
[py_objc_timestamp] NSISO8601DateFormatOptions add up to: 2035
2021-04-04 20:09:43+02:00 [py_objc_timestamp] timestamp from PyObjC
```